# Regarding mat-card-title not aligning center

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-card

I've use mat-card, in that I've used mat-card-title, for that I've used `style="text-align:center";` but it's not aligning center

```
<mat-card style="text-align: center;">
  <mat-card-header >
<mat-card-title style="text-align: center;">
  spreadsheet
</mat-card-title>
</mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
    <div id="spreadsheet"></div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And this is the screenshot of the browser:

[image]

Comment: Add style to mat-card-header, It would align center

Comment: Still no changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text align not having effect because mat-header tag only having the width of its content. You can try like this

```
<mat-card >
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <mat-card-title>spreadsheet</mat-card-title>
  </div>
  <mat-card-content>
<div id="spreadsheet">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

html file:

```
<mat-card class="title_center">
    <mat-card-title>spreadsheet</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

css file:

```
.title_center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```